# Find newest value in mysql database

Tags: mysql

I have two tables that store infotmation about images that are uploaded to a site call image and audit.  When the image is uploaded it's path is stored in image.imageLocation and when it is used for an audit the auditID is saved to the same table.  The auditID is the value used for joining the tables together.

I am trying to make a query which will tell me the latest audit for which the image was used using the date the audit was made which is audit.dateStart.

The query I have so far is...

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT image.imageID AS newest_image, image.userID AS image_userID,
           image.auditID as image_auditID, image.type AS image_type,
           image.imageLocation AS location
    from image
) image
LEFT JOIN audit ON image_auditID = audit.auditID
WHERE image_userID = '$id' AND image_type = 'standard'
      AND dateStart = MAX(dateStart)
GROUP by location
```

This throws an error saying improper use of GROUP.

Any help will be gratefully received

This is the table structure

```
audit

auditID     varchar(255)        
userID      int(11)     
dateStart       date        
dateEnd     date    
auditName       varchar     
auditDesc       varchar     
imagesUploaded  tinyint 
actionPlan      varchar     
auditComplete   tinyint 
dateComplete    datetime

image

imageID         int(10)     
name            varchar(255)        
auditID         varchar(255)        
imageGrade          int(1)      
exposure            varchar(255)        
positioning         varchar(255)        
patient         varchar(255)        
equipment           varchar(255)        
positioningReason   varchar(255)        
exposureReason  varchar(255)        
patientReason   varchar(255)        
comment         varchar(255)        
auditDate           datetime    
imageLocation   varchar(255)        
thumbnail           text        
xrayType            varchar(10)     
type            varchar(255)        
userID          int(11) 

Some sample data

imageID = 563
name = standard_16.jpg
auditID = 1360318160843025059
imageLocation = upload/2/standards/standard_16.jpg
type = standard
userID = 2

imageID = 565
name = standard_18.jpg
auditID = 1360318160843025059
imageLocation = upload/2/standards/standard_18.jpg
type = standard
userID = 2

imageID = 566
name = standard_18.jpg
auditID = 13603248241777655575
imageLocation = upload/2/standards/standard_18.jpg
type = standard
userID = 2

auditID = 1360318160843025059
userID = 2
dateStart = 2013-02-14

auditID = 13603248241777655575
userID = 2
dateStart = 2013-02-09
```

As you can see the same images can be used for more than one audit and I want to know which audit used the image last, in this case the result would be auditID 1360318160843025059

Comment: Can you add the complete (exact) error message?

Comment: that was exactly it, improper use of GROUP function

Comment: Also, why are you doing that weird subquery in the first select? Is there any reason you can't just remove the `select * from (` and `) image`?

Comment: yes, it gives fields aliases because one of them is identical in both tables

Comment: But you don't need a subquery to alias the fields names..

Comment: That was the way I was taught to do it, I'm happy to change it if there is a better way to do it

Comment: brilliant, I'll give that a go in future, thanks

Comment: @tatty27 can you post some sample data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using a subquery. This subquery will get the `max(dateStart)` for each audit. You will then join this result to the `audit` table to return all of the details of the row with the max date:

```
SELECT 
  i.imageID AS newest_image, 
  i.userID AS image_userID, 
  i.auditID as image_auditID, 
  i.type AS image_type, 
  i.imageLocation AS location,
  a1.*
FROM image i
LEFT JOIN audit a1
  on i.auditID = a1.auditID
INNER JOIN 
(
  select auditID, max(dateStart) MaxDate
  from audit
  group by auditID
) a2
  on a1.auditID = a2.auditID
  and a1.dateStart = a2.MaxDate
WHERE i.userID = '$id' 
  AND i.type = 'standard'
```

Edit, if you only what image/audit was last, then you can use:

```
SELECT i.imageID AS newest_image, 
  i.userID AS image_userID, 
  i.auditID as image_auditID, 
  i.type AS image_type, 
  i.imageLocation AS location,
  a1.*
FROM image i
LEFT JOIN audit a1
  on i.auditID = a1.auditID
INNER JOIN 
(
  select max(dateStart) MaxDate
  from audit
) a2
  on a1.dateStart = a2.MaxDate
WHERE i.type = 'standard';
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c0ed7/6)

---

Just another guess:

```
SELECT i.imageID AS newest_image, 
  i.userID AS image_userID, 
  i.auditID AS image_auditID, 
  i.type AS image_type, 
  i.imageLocation AS location,
  a.*
FROM image i
  JOIN audit a
    ON i.auditID = a.auditID
  JOIN 
    (
    SELECT i.imageLocation, MAX(a.dateStart) MaxDate
    FROM image i
      JOIN audit a
        ON i.auditID = a.auditID
    WHERE i.userID = '$id' 
      AND i.type = 'standard' 
    GROUP BY i.imageLocation 
    ) g
    ON  g.MaxDate = a.dateStart
    AND g.imageLocation = i.imageLocation
WHERE i.userID = '$id' 
  AND i.type = 'standard'
```

Comment: HI, thanks for your help but that query results in showing all of the instances the image was used rather than just the latest

Comment: I've just added it and I'm getting the same result

Comment: @tatty27 can you post your table structure and some sample data or even better create a sql fiddle? -- http://www.sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: @tatty27 do you create a new `auditid` for each record? Seeing the table details would be helpful

Comment: sorry, I just thought I had a syntax error, sample data added, I hope it helps.  Each image can only have one auditID, the auditID is the unique ID in the audit table

Comment: the first query still shows each time the image was used rather than just the last time.  The second query just shows the last images used as you said, but I need to know the last audit each image was used

Comment: @tatty27 can you edit the sql fiddle with more same data and the full table structure?

Comment: @bluefeet: The problem is that the OP (tatty27) has misnamed the `image` table. The relationship is not 1-audit-to-many-images but a many-to-many relayionship stored in table `image`. You need to `GROUP BY imageLocation` in the subquery.

Comment: @ypercube I think they might be able to join on the image table using the `auditDate` field but without seeing more data it is very difficult

Comment: @tatty27 so based on the sample what do you expect the result to be?

Comment: @bluefeet: De nada. Here's the query in the fiddle with the new data: [fiddle-2](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1fe48/10) (with two veriosn, one for `user_id=2` and one slightly modified, for all `user_id`)

Comment: @bluefeet based on the sample I expected the result to show me that standard_18.jpg was last used for audit ending 5059, stanard_img_1.jpg was last used for audit ending 5483 and then the auditID's for the images that that have only been used once

Comment: @tatty27: See the fiddle link, in the above comment.

Comment: @bluefeet, thank you very much for all of your help, it has been greatly appreciated, I will have a play with sql fiddle for future reference

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 SELECT * FROM (
SELECT image.imageID AS newest_image, image.userID AS image_userID,
       image.auditID as image_auditID, image.type AS image_type,
       image.imageLocation AS location
 from image
 GROUP by location
              ) image
LEFT JOIN audit ON image_auditID = audit.auditID
WHERE image_userID = '$id' AND image_type = 'standard'
  AND dateStart = MAX(dateStart)
```

EDIT.

```
 SELECT image.imageID AS newest_image, image.userID AS image_userID,
   image.auditID as image_auditID, image.type AS image_type,
   image.imageLocation AS location
   from image
  LEFT JOIN audit ON image.userID = audit.auditID
  INNER JOIN 
 (
   select max(dateStart) MaxDate
   from audit
  ) audit2
  on audit.dateStart = audit2.MaxDate
  WHERE  image.type = 'standard'
  GROUP by image.imageLocation
```

[**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0962a0/18)

Comment: HI, it gives exactly the same error 'invalid use of group function'

Comment: any simple data of your tables ?

Comment: I'm afraid it returns an empty result